# Set NutritionInformation Schema Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-apps-script, schema

I'm attempting to set [Google Rich Snippets](https://schema.org/NutritionInformation) for a Nutrition Information page dynamically. Basically taking each table cell and associating them with their respective property value (calories, fatContent, ect). Here is the page: https://www.pizzerialocale.com/nutrition

Below is a shortened snippet of some of the nutrition info I'm trying to associate with their respective property values:

```
jQuery(function($) {

var servingsizeClass = 'servingsize';
var descriptionClass   = 'description';
var fibercontentClass   = 'fibercontent';


var logOutput     = false;

(function(){

    // Build Data
    var servingsize = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(servingsizeClass)).map(function(e){return e.textContent});
    var name = "Nutrition";
    var description = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(descriptionClass)).map(function(e){return e.textContent});
    var fibercontent = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(fibercontentClass)).map(function(e){return e.textContent});

    if (servingsize.length && description.length) {

        var data = {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "NutritionInformation",
          "mainEntity": []
        };

        buildItem = (s,d) => {

            var item = {
                    "servingSize": null,
            "name": null,
            "description": null,
            "fiberContent": null,
            "@id": "http://schemaapp.com/db/Winston#NutritionInformation1"
                  };

            item['servingSize'] = s;
            item['name'] = n;
            item['description'] = d;
            item['fiberContent'] = f;

            return item;
        }

        data['mainEntity'] = servingSize.map(function(s,i){return buildItem(s,answers[i])});

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = "application/ld+json";
        script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

        if (logOutput){
              console.log(script.outerHTML);
        }

    }

})(document);
    });
```

The problem is once I take the page through [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?id=CyZ_HFa5KgHTS5iKK1gCVw), it doesn't pick up **theservingSize**, **name**, **description**, and **fiberContent** properties. Any help would be appreciated on how I can get these properties read by Google.

Comment: This exact function loaded fine for another page and was registered properly by Google's Rich Results. I don't see why that would be an issue.

Comment: @Cooper There are no third-party tools involved here. This is just pure javascript being used to add JSON data to a page with a basic HTML table on it. It's not adding the JSON data. I'm simply using the Rich Results Test to see if its picking up the properties. I did specify my problem. I've since edited it to clarify further what I'm looking for assistance with.

Comment: I just went and read about Rich Results and as it turns out I should have passed on this because I don't know anything about it. Sorry to bother you.